# How to trick QtCreator about the existence of a macro definition

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake, build-system

QtCreator has some problems with the code model when using some of the fancy C++11 features in a C++/Qt project. In my case: templated alias, as the following:

```
template<class T> using Ptr = QSharedPointer<T>;

QSharedPointer<SomeClass> myPtr = ...;
myPtr->...                               // will complete

Ptr<SomeClass> myPtr = ...;              // not even parsed as a type...
myPtr->...                               // won't complete
```

So I thought about just macro-hacking my `Ptr` definition *when QtCreator parses the file*, but of course use the nice templated alias syntax *when the compiler parses the file*. Something like:

```
#ifdef QT_CREATOR
# define Ptr QSharedPointer
#else
template<class T> using Ptr = QSharedPointer<T>;
#endif
```

Putting a macro definition in the .pro file using a `DEFINES += -D...` won't work, as QtCreator is smart enough to use them in the code model (which is nice, of course). Also, `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D...` is being parsed correctly (sadly).

How can I "trick" QtCreator that there is a macro defined, but (for the compiler) there isn't (or the other way around)?

PS: I'm using the most recent version (2.7), and also tried 2.6.

Comment: Try to use experimental ClangCodeModel plugin. Since it uses libclang for completion/highlighting, it can parse everithing that clang supports. https://qt.gitorious.org/+qtcreator-clang-edgers/qtcreator-clang-stable https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qtcreator-clang-git/

Answer (score 1):

The following worked to trick QtCreator about a macro definition.

In the .pro project file, I added the following line:

```
QMAKE_CXX = $${QMAKE_CXX} -D_IS_BEING_COMPILED
```

This means, the macro `_IS_BEING_COMPILED` will be defined. But QtCreator (at least version 2.7) doesn't parse the contents of `QMAKE_CXX` for flags (I think, for a good reason). So: QtCreator doesn't see this macro, but when compiling, it's there. Thus, a preprocessor branch like this will do the job:

```
#ifdef _IS_BEING_COMPILED
template<class T> using Ptr = QSharedPointer<T>;
#else
# define Ptr QSharedPointer
# error `Ptr` is a macro, but it should not!
#endif
```

Now, QtCreator uses the macro workaround to introduce the alias, which isn't perfect but since it's only the IDE which is hacked and not the code base itself, this is OK. QtCreator will parse instances of `Ptr` now and also complete members.

Comment: @AnatolyS What do you mean? You doubt that this did the trick?

Comment: I meant that I would use QSharedPointer without this trick. As for me it is a pair of crutches for QtCreator.

Comment: I want abstraction of the pointer type I use in the code base, i.e. to be able to switch to `std::shared_ptr` at any time. The macro hack is acceptable since there is no other symbol named `Ptr` in my code (would be confusing anyway). (So even in a C++03 project I'd use a macro straight away (since 03 doesn't support templated type aliases).) I feel safe to just trick QtCreator (and not the compiler) that it's a macro. It works, and effectively it doesn't modify my code base. ;)